# Getting results even if row doesn't exist in JOIN table

Tags: mysql, azure

I store 2 different backup types (Full or Log) and also have 2 different server types (Local or Azure) this query below brings back the correct results as 3 rows are returned, however when i delete a row which corresponds to this line in the SQL query:

```
AND (r4.Type = 'Full' AND r4.Server = 'Azure')
```

Only 2 rows are then retrieved because their isn't a row which exists in the table for type 'Full' and server 'Azure'

This is the query i've done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   r1.Tenant,
   r1.Name,
   r1.DBName,
   r1.Server as Server1,
   r1.Type as Type1,
   r1.Date as Date1,
   r2.Type as Type2,
   r2.Date as Date2,
   r2.Server as Server2,
   r3.Type as Type3,
   r3.Date as Date3,
   r3.Server as Server3,
   r4.Type as Typ4,
   r4.Date as Date4,
   r4.Server as Server4
FROM #Results AS r1
JOIN #Results AS r2 ON r2.DBName = r1.DBName 
JOIN #Results AS r3 ON r3.DBName = r1.DBName 
JOIN #Results AS r4 ON r4.DBName = r1.DBName 
WHERE
(r1.TYPE = 'Full' AND r1.Server = 'Local') AND
(r2.TYPE = 'Log' AND r2.Server = 'Local') AND
(r3.Type = 'Full' AND r3.Server = 'Azure') AND
(r4.Type = 'Log' AND r4.Server = 'Azure')
ORDER BY r1.Tenant
```

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, this is the data retrieved. I expect another row containing the following:

- Log, Local
- Full, Local
- Log, Azure
- NULL, NULL (as a Full Azure backup doesn't exist)

Here is the data within the Result table:

[image]

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead. Add sample data and expected output so we can provide a more detail answer

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Even that doesn't work. Still only 2 results are retrieved

Comment: As I said, show us sample data and expected output.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Added sample data

Comment: You only include desire output. Please add the source data. Is like ask a magician do the trick without the proper setup.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Theirs too many rows, do you not get the idea from the above?

Comment: Yes. I get the idea. But if you want a detail answer you need to provide detail information. Of course I can do it but that take time.  Just prepare a sample with some data. I already start a demo waiting for your data.   http://rextester.com/AWXAO24175

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Added some more sample data

Comment: I can't copy paste from pictures. Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why  ... Put I have a better idea now

Comment: LEFT JOIN and any limit in the where clause that is referenced as a left join NEEDS to have that limit placed on the join not in the where.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN` since you still want a result row for r1 and r2 when r3 and r4 are null.

You probably tried modifying all of the `JOIN` statments, but got the same results... Here's the problem. When you try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t2.some_column = 'a value'
```

The LEFT JOIN is working properly, and returning a row with null t2 values, however this row is thrown away in the WHERE clause.  `t2.some_column = 'a value'` Can't be true, since t2.some_column = NULL

Solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id AND t2.some_column = 'a value'
```

Now any a t2 row without `some_column = 'a value' won't be included in the result set, however that's okay because we're using LEFT JOIN, so that row will consist of t1 values with NULL t2 values

Alternatively you could try: `WHERE t2.is IS NULL OR t2.some_column = 'a value'`

In relation to your query:

````
```select ... 
FROM #Results AS r1 
LEFT JOIN #Results AS r2 ON r2.DBName = r1.DBName AND (r2.TYPE = 'Log' AND r2.Server = 'Local') 
LEFT JOIN #Results AS r3 ON r3.DBName = r1.DBName AND (r3.Type = 'Full' AND r3.Server = 'Azure') 
LEFT JOIN #Results AS r4 ON r4.DBName = r1.DBName AND (r4.Type = 'Log' AND r4.Server = 'Azure') 
WHERE (r1.TYPE = 'Full' AND r1.Server = 'Local') 
ORDER BY r1.Tenant```
````

Comment: Can you write a query which corresponds to my query please? Because I've just tried this, it nearly works but only returns Full backups on Local rows

Comment: Added an update to the answer. Note that I'm assuming that no columns in r1 will be null

Comment: Thanks! What r1, r2 and r3 could be null? Would i have to follow the same procedure you took?

Comment: Honestly I didn't really notice that you were doing all of these joins on a single table when I first answered... I would probably go with the answer @JuanCarlosOropeza posted

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Tenant,  Name, DBName,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Server = 'local' and Type = 'full'
                  THEN Date END) as FullLocalDate,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Server = 'local' and Type = 'log'
                  THEN Date END) as LogLocalDate,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Server = 'azure' and Type = 'full'
                  THEN Date END) as FullAzureDate,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Server = 'azure' and Type = 'log'
                  THEN Date END) as LogAzureDate
 FROM #Results r
 GROUP BY Tenant,  Name, DBName
```

I remove the columns Server1 Server2 ... because is already part of the date information. But can be add it if need it.

Comment: did you try it? any comments?